# How to do column-wise and row-wise operations in SQL

Tags: sql, transformation, data-manipulation

I have a question about row-wise and column-wise operations in a SQL query. I will demonstrate my question with the following example data table:

```
Person           Income      Hours worked   Day
A                100         10             1
A                200         9              2
B                300         8              1 
B                400         7              2
C                500         6              1
C                600         5              2
```

I want to write a query where I can get the total income, hours worked and income per hour for (A + B) and C. That is:

```
Person           Income      Hours worked   Income / Hour
A + B            1000        34             1000 / 34
C                1100        11             1100 / 11
```

How would I do this in SQL?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How about some tags? What flavour of SQL would be a good start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNION ALL in subqueries

```
SELECT Person, Income, [Hours worked], [Income / Hour]    
FROM (
  SELECT 'A + B' AS Person,
          SUM(Income) AS Income,
          SUM([Hours worked]) AS [Hours worked],
          SUM([Day]) AS [Hours worked]
  FROM dbo.TableName
  WHERE Person IN('A', 'B')           

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 'C' AS Person,
          SUM(Income) AS Income,
          SUM([Hours worked]) AS [Hours worked],
          SUM([Day]) AS [Hours worked]
  FROM dbo.TableName
  WHERE Person = 'C'
) x
```

If you want to sort you can apply the `ORDER BY` on the outer query.

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL, we could do something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.Person IN ('A','B') THEN 'A + B' ELSE t.Person END AS Person
     , SUM(t.Income)                                                  AS Income
     , SUM(t.`Hours Worked`)                                          AS `Hours Worked`
     , CONCAT( SUM(t.Income) , ' / ' , SUM(t.`Hours Worked`) )        AS `Income / Hour`
 FROM mytable t
GROUP BY CASE WHEN t.Person IN ('A','B') THEN 'A + B' ELSE t.Person END
```

This same pattern will work in most other relational databases, but with different handling for escaping wonky column names.

For Oracle, enclose identifiers in double quotes instead of backticks. (i.e. replace the backticks with double quotes, and also enclose column names that contain lower case letters or other special characters.)

For SQL Server, enclose identifiers in square brackets... `[Hours Worked]`.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of giving another way to do it, here's a UNION approach :

```
SELECT 'A + B', sum(income) as income, sum(hoursworked) as hoursworked sum(income)/sum(hoursworked) as income_hour
FROM yourtable
WHERE person in ('A','B')

UNION ALL

SELECT person, sum(income) as income, sum(hoursworked) as hoursworked sum(income)/sum(hoursworked) as income_hour
FROM yourtable
WHERE person NOT in ('A','B')
GROUP BY person
```

*Edit* : Tim was faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression to treat rows with persons `A`, `B` as the same and aggregate.

```
select 
case when person in ('A','B') then 'A+B' else person end as person
,sum(income) as income
,sum(hoursworked) as hoursworked
,sum(income)/sum(hoursworked) as income_hour
from yourtable
group by case when person in ('A','B') then 'A+B' else person end
```